# Vercel Build Error: It looks like you're using options meant for '@sanity/preview-kit/client'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel, sanity

Hi Im having an odd issue with Vercel deployment because of sanity, this is the Vercel build error:

**Error: It looks like you're using options meant for '@sanity/preview-kit/client', such as 'encodeSourceMapAtPath', 'encodeSourceMap', 'studioUrl' and 'logger'. Make sure you're using the right import.**

I had "studioUrl" param in my sanity client config but I deleted it, and pushed it to Git Hub for Vercel to build but it keeps throwing the same error.

**this is my sanity client config:**

```
import { createClient } from "next-sanity";
import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url';

export const client = createClient({
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID,
    dataset: "production",
    apiVersion: "2022-03-25",
    token: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_API_TOKEN,
    useCdn: true,
  });
  
const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client);

export const urlFor = (source) => builder.image(source);
```

I tried to build my project locally and there is no error.

Answer (score 3):

I change code in my `sanityClient.ts`

Previous Code

```
import { createClient } from 'next-sanity' (get error in this code)
```

New Code

```
import { createClient } from "@sanity/client" ( error solved)
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue today. Not sure when this happened because I'm using the same next-sanity version in 2 different projects, but in one of them the @sanity/cli version in package-lock seems to be 5.4.2 (the one that works) and in other project is 6.1.7 (this one doesn't work).

**In order to fix the issue**, I had to migrate to next-sanity v5 (currently 5.4.2) making the required changes (is a small set of changes) mentioned in this [link](https://github.com/sanity-io/next-sanity/blob/main/MIGRATE-v4-to-v5-pages-router.md) which are better explained and detailed in this [page](https://github.com/sanity-io/preview-kit/blob/main/MIGRATION.md).

Basically the changes consist on:

- Replacing usePreview pattern by useLiveQuery.
- Removing PreviewSuspense since it doesn't exist anymore and replace it by providing a a behavior when the default value is returned (useLiveQuery accepts a default value that will be returned now instead of null).
- Creating a small LiveQueryProvider that accepts the preview token.

All this steps are better explained in the links above, but that's it in short.

Another possibility of resolving this problem in case of not being able to update the version could be to use pnpm or yarn to specify a version of @sanity/client (5.4.2) to make it work with next-sanity 4.3.3 but I didn't try this to confirm it works.

Hope it helps!